# Hyphen and ellipsis overlap for certain long titles

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, truncation

Under certain circumstances, a browser's word break and text overflow functionalities collide, producing a hyphen that overlaps the ellipsis. This is how [this user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1232767/thor#user-panel-questions) looks like in the latest Firefox on macOS Monterey:

[image]

but it might happen in other places as well. I guess this is the result of some conflicting or otherwise suboptimal CSS rules?